# how to install a local version of GLIBC on RHEL (without su permissions)

Tags: linux, redhat-enterprise-linux, glibc

The glibc on the RHEL system I am using is old. I don't have su permissions on that system.

Anyone knows how to install a local, updated version of GLIBC on my user account, without the need to have su permissions?

Thanks!

Comment: you have to use yum package manager. Figure out how to retrieve your root password.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't lost the root password... I am not an admin on this system so I can't have a root password.

Comment: this is a system wide setting, you can't have a local instance of glibc unless you use docker or some container.